# Stop jQuery Fade Loop and add Hover Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, loops

I am trying to implement a fade in- fade out loop in jQuery

[You can see it here](http://jsfiddle.net/6WtAs/2/)

But this does not work the way I want it to. This code just stops the Fade loop when I hover over the `point1`.

I want the code to work in such a way that when you hover over one of the points (`point1`, `point2` etc.), the fade loop will stop/pause, and only the specified `.trip` will show, then on hover out/mouseout, the fade loop will start over from the top.

For example:

If I hover over `<div class="point2">Hover Point 2</div>`, the loop should stop, and only `<div id="2" class="trip two">Item2</div>` should be shown. Or if I hover over `<div class="point1">Hover Point 1</div>` during the loop, the loop should stop and `<div id="2" class="trip one">Item1</div>`, should be shown, and once on mouseout, the loop should start from the top.

Tried a bunch of stuff, help please.
How do I fix this?

Comment: a jsFiddle maybe or a jsBin so that we can look at it and debug...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my take on it:

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="1" class="trip 1">Item1</div>
    <div id="2" class="trip">Item2</div>
    <div id="3" class="trip">Item3</div>
</div>
<hr>
<br/>
<div class="point" id="show1">Hover Point 1</div>
<br/>
<div class="point" id="show2">Hover Point 2</div>
<br/>
<div class="point" id="show3">Hover Point 3</div>
```

JS

```
var $elem = $('#main .trip'), l = $elem.length, i = 0;

function go() {
    $elem.eq(i % l).fadeIn(700, function() {
        $elem.eq(i % l).fadeOut(700, go);
        i++;
    })
}

go();

var tripToShow = 0;

$('.point').hover(function(){
    tripToShow = this.id.replace('show', '');
    $('.trip').stop(true).hide();
    $('#'+tripToShow).show();
},function(){
    $('.trip').hide();
    i = 1;
    tripToShow = 0;
    go();
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/stevoperisic/GKZ2F/

Answer (score 2):

You are correctly stopping the animation, but then you need to display the proper element and hide all others.  Also, you want to re-start the loop by calling `go` when you mouseout.

```
$('.point1').hover(function(){
    $('.trip').stop(true).hide();    
    $("#1").show();
},function(){
    i = 0;
    go();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MtmxN/68/

Comment: Thanks this worked, but I tried adding hover functions to other points, which I will need, but it seems a bit shaky with more than one. Please see the updates I made to the same jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/MtmxN/72/

Comment: Actually I fixed it, it was just missing the hide(). on the .trip